# cant totally delete maatwebsite/excel from project

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have installed maatwebsite/excel to my laravel project . And then deleted it by deleting its require from composer.json and doing composer update . Also deleted excel.php from app/config . Now Im getting Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider' not found .

```
public function createProvider($provider)
    {
        return new $provider($this->app);
    }
```

I did route clear,cache clear , dump autoload . But nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `config/app.php` the `providers` array, and delete that line from there if you manually add that one.